# DNS timeouts sporadically appears when communicating with gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-speech

I am getting every few days the following:

```
/Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/google-cloud-speech-v1-0.9.0/lib/google/cloud/speech/v1/speech/client.rb:345:in `rescue in long_running_recognize': 14:DNS resolution failed for speech.googleapis.com: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=speech.googleapis.com is_balancer=0: Timeout while contacting DNS servers. debug_error_string:{UNKNOWN:DNS resolution failed for speech.googleapis.com: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=speech.googleapis.com is_balancer=0: Timeout while contacting DNS servers {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-02-20T14:12:54.665638+02:00"}} (Google::Cloud::UnavailableError)
/Users/..../.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2/gems/grpc-1.50.0-x86_64-darwin/src/ruby/lib/grpc/generic/active_call.rb:29:in `check_status': 14:DNS resolution failed for speech.googleapis.com: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=speech.googleapis.com is_balancer=0: Timeout while contacting DNS servers. debug_error_string:{UNKNOWN:DNS resolution failed for speech.googleapis.com: C-ares status is not ARES_SUCCESS qtype=A name=speech.googleapis.com is_balancer=0: Timeout while contacting DNS servers {grpc_status:14, created_time:"2023-02-20T14:12:54.665638+02:00"}} (GRPC::Unavailable)
```

I tried another ISP/router but its still the same.
What am I doing wrong?!